# nested LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I read this code in the Hello Android book and i dont know why to write two LinearLayout.
I could be one of these remove or move to other?
Why do we use nested LinearLayout? What does it do?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="30dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/main_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
            android:textSize="24.5sp"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/continue_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/continue_label"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/new_game_label"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/about_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/about_label" />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/exit_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/exit_label"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

the horizontal layout is laying out the elements horizontally like:

`[element][element][element]`

the verterical one is laying it out like this:

```
[element]
[element]
[element]
```

so with the xml format shown it would be a row of buttons on top of eachother vertically..
if you don't need that layout, then yes, you could simplify it by removing one.

hard to explain in text, but this is kind of what it would look like:

```
----Outer (Horizontal) layout-----
|                                |
|  ---Inner (Vertical) layout-   |
|  |       [Textview]        |   |
|  |       [Button]          |   |
|  |       [Button]          |   |
|  |       [Button]          |   |
|  ---------------------------   |
----------------------------------
```

with the textview/buttons moving down vertically.

#### Edit:

Actually since the outer layout has

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

it will just take up the whole screen, with 30 padding.
Then the inner layout will fit to the content inside it vertically, and max out the width horizontally.

I think you probably don't need the outer layout.. you could get the same effect with the proper attributes in just one `LinearLayout`

Comment: Thanks for answer. Why to used inner LinearLayout of layout_width and layout_height? so why the content inside(buttons) to used layout_height and width if the inner LinearLayout used for sort and organize to the content inside(Buttons and textview)?

Comment: sorry, not really sure what you're asking.. Are you asking why there is a layout_height and width on the layout and also on the elements inside? The height/width would control that individual element's height/width. `LinearLayout` is an element too, so it would control the size of itself there as well.

Comment: The inner layout may be used to center the buttons and TextView within the overall layout if there is more than enough room to display everything on the screen and based upon this answer provided. The height and width of the internal views (such as the Buttons and TextView) will still be used to stretch the view (fill_parent) to fit the inner LinearLayout or to use the view to it's minimal size (wrap_content) within the inner LinearLayout. 

Recap: Inner layout is used to organize how all the internal views are laid out, while each view still describes its own size (within its viewgroup).

Answer (score 0):

Here 2 LinearLayout's used to maintain the direction of layout

1st or the parent LinearLayout will manage to cover the whole screen because of

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

with the

> background color

and Add everything in horizontal in queue followed because of

```
android:orientation="vertical"[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

2nd LinearLayout or nested one will put everything in center because of

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

will take only space as the item require because of

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

and everything will be arranged in vertical order because of

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```